# сравнение 2-х картинок в С#

Tags: c#, изображения

Ранее использовал код ниже:

```
        public static bool ImageCompare(Image image1, Image image2, int tolerance)
    {
        var img1 = (Bitmap)image1;
        var img2 = (Bitmap)image2;

        if (img1.Size != img2.Size)
        {
            return false;
        }

        float diff = 0;

        for (var y = 0; y < img1.Height; y++)
        {
            for (var x = 0; x < img1.Width; x++)
            {
                var pixel1 = img1.GetPixel(x, y);
                var pixel2 = img2.GetPixel(x, y);

                diff += Math.Abs(pixel1.R - pixel2.R);
                diff += Math.Abs(pixel1.G - pixel2.G);
                diff += Math.Abs(pixel1.B - pixel2.B);
            }
        }
        var percentDiff = 100 * (diff / 255) / (img1.Width * img1.Height * 3);

        return percentDiff < tolerance;
    }
```

Сейчас для методов класса Bitmap вижу следующее сообщение:[image: сообщение]

Comment: Ну тут явно с операционкой проблема. Прийдётся размер картинки другим способом проверять, либо менять операционку, если устройство поддерживает её смену и есть возможноть переустановить..

Comment: WinForms? System.Drawing? Гвоздями приколочено к Винде. Возьмите какую-нибудь кроссплатформенную библиотеку для работы с изображениями. Например, здесь описаны несколько штук: [.NET Core Image Processing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-image-processing/)

Comment: ЗЫ: GetPixel - чудовищно медленно! Используйте [LockBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) и работайте с байтами изображения напрямую, если уж берёте System.Drawing.

Comment: То, что вас предупреждает - это нормально, ибо данные свойства будут работать только в OS Windows. Если вам не нужна кроссплатформенность, то советую указать целевую платформу своему проекту (что-то типа `net7-windows`), тогда предупреждать не будет. Если вам нужна поддержка разных OS, то варианта 2: 1. Найти аналог, который поддерживает все OS. 2. Реализовать под каждую OS свой метод, обернув его в `#if WINDOWS`.

Comment: Не по теме: это оооочень медленный код. Можно быстрее, раз в 1000.

Comment: Size - это просто Heigth * Width? Тогда просто замени (img1.Size != img2.Size) на (img1.Height * img1.Width != img2.Height * img2.Width).